# linkd not displaying for anonymous user

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to make node/add URL appear on front of site to anonymous user and when clicked, it redirects to login or register page. drupal hides links automatically, any help please. I'm using drupal 7

Comment: How you adding node/add link on site front page?

Comment: node/add is run through permissions (anonymous does not have). Just add this link l('Add Content', 'user') then it goes to login page automatically. Then you might want to redirect after login to node/add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating a block as follows

Go to `admin/structure/block` and add a new block as follows
[image]

set show block for anonymous user.

[image]

and set the Region where you want to display the link on Front page. and if you want to display the link only at front page. make the following settings

[image]

Comment: That is correct, however, OP must still redirect away from Access Denied page to user login page.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Oh! yes you're right! I missed that point.

Comment: At least now with your method there is a referrer so a proper determination of redirection can be made.

Comment: Thks pals, I formerly created the links with admin/structure/menus before which disappeared after on the front page. I've used your answer to create links as block which works perfect. Also I could redirect anonymous user to login or register before adding a node with drupal.org/project/logintoboggan. Thks again.